# swiftUICharts lIbrary creating a LineView with SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Using an Example of SwiftUICharts, I have used the following, to create a line chart:

```
    **LineView(data: [8,23.5,54.8,32,12,37,7,23,43])**
```

And it works very nicely:-)

However I want to plot **x,y rather than just y** values

I have tried

Code Block
LineView(data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [8,23.5,54.8,32,12,37,7,23,43])

(With and without the comma which separates the 2 bracketed “terms”)

And

LineView(data: [(1,8),(2,23.5),(3,54.8),(4,32),(5,12),(6,37),(7,7),(8,23),(9,43)])

All gave errors

Any idea how I should present the data to obtain the x,y line graph?

TIA,

Phil.

Comment: You should ask this to `SwiftUICharts` owner.

Comment: Well, I was hoping this would be an easy one for someone to answer, hence not a code example.
The Library can be found at:

https://github.com/AppPear/ChartView

Comment: Well, I was hoping this would be an easy one for someone to answer, hence not a code example.
The Library can be found at (with simple examples):

https://github.com/AppPear/ChartView